# How to add double quotes to the string?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark-1.6

I have a Json-like string like this:

```
{cid: {ABCD[1]_TYPE, [text]: alphabets, time: 1/12/2010, author: xyz, best_chapter: 10.5}
```

And I need to add double quotes to every string to make it look like a real Json:

```
{"cid": {"ABCD[1]_TYPE", "[text]": "alphabets", "time": "1/12/2010", "author": "xyz", "best_chapter": "10.5"}}
```

I've already done this:

```
val jsonString = str.replaceAll("(\\w+/.)", "\"$1\"")
```

My regex fails and it escapes the Square Brackets like this:

```
{"cid": {"ABCD"["1"]"_TYPE", [""text""]: "alphabets", "time": "1/12/2010", "author": "xyz", "best_chapter": "10.5"}}
```

Any idea how to make the double quotes include that.

Comment: In general, you can't do this reliably with a single regex.  A pipeline of multiple regexes could in some cases get you something close to what you want.

Comment: Can you try `([\\w\\[\\]\\.\\/]+.)(?=[:,}])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to describe everything that should be quoted, and escaping all the special characters, it might be easier to describe what should *not* be quoted.

```
str.replaceAll("([^\\s:,{}]+)", "\"$1\"")
```